# Refine core info from string

Tags: python, machine-learning, text-mining, n-gram

A list of fruits with details in strings. I want to refine the core info, i.e. the fruit name from the strings.

Some of them have 1 word in name (e.g. Apple, Grape), some have 2 (Water melon, Start fruit).

I tried ngram way:

```
from nltk import ngrams
from collections import Counter

strings = [
"Apples Fresh Golden Delicious",
"Apples Fresh Red Delicious 12",
"Apple Sliced 12",
"Apple Diced 24",
"Water melon Fresh Petite Green on the turn",
"16 count Star fruit",
"8 count Star fruit",
"4 count Star fruit",
"Grapes Red Fresh Seedless",
"Grapes Green Fresh Seedless",
"Orange Naval Fresh 100 Count",
"Orange Naval Fresh 48 Count",
"Orange Naval Fresh 24 Count",
"Orange Naval Fresh 12 Count"]

basket = []

for s in strings:
    grams = ngrams(s.split(), 1) # 2 for 2-gram

    for g in grams:
      basket.append("-".join(g))

print (Counter(basket))
```

1-gram:

```
Counter({'Fresh': 9, 'Orange': 4, 'Naval': 4})
```

2-gram:

```
Counter({'Orange-Naval': 4, 'Naval-Fresh': 4, 'count-Star': 3})
```

Obviously it's not working well.

What would be a better way? Thank you.

Comment: If you need only a solution for fruits, I would hold a list of all fruits(maybe 100) and search for them directly(using string comparison or regex).

Comment: @yoav_aaa, there are unknown/exotic fruits...so assuming this is the first and only document to produce a list of fruits.

Comment: Missed you here, what is an unknown fruit?

Comment: @yoav_aaa, for something we don't even know it's a fruit, e.g. duku langsat, rambutan etc.